# Is it safe to Update and/or Insert records into an accounting software's database? (Pastel Evolution)

Tags: odbc, crm, accounting

Our CRM system can post transactions to our accounts software (Pastel Evolution), but it doesn't perform the required currency conversion. Both systems have different "base" currencies (because of our location), so the figure thats sent to Pastel evolution is right, but it is reflected in the wrong currency.
The CRM uses an ODBC connection to post figures to Evolution.

I can make a tool which sits between the two systems which can update and/or insert the transactions into Pastel, by mimicking what the CRM would have done if it was doing the POST.

Is it safe for me to mimic and/or update these transactions directly in the Pastel database? 
Is it common for important validation to be performed in the ODBC layer, and if so, can I tap into an applications ODBC, or is there a custom driver built by the CRM to communicate with the DB?

Comment: Pastel have a long history of providing good support for third-party integration, APIs and whatnot. Ask them what the supported way of doing this is.

Comment: There might be another stackexchange site that this question could be migrated to. It is not suitable for serverfault.

Comment: @kasperd - I can't think of one. This is pretty specific to this application, so it's a valid sysadmin question. Unfortunately, one with a low chance of a definitive answer from anyone that hasn't had deep experience with Pastel, so that's why I answered with caution and advice to ask the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

These are all, really, questions for your vendor(s). There could easily be application logic that you are avoiding or subverting by making changes directly in the Evolution DB, and those missed rules could cause things to break. That's bad news for audit and tax time.

That said, if I were in your shoes and also had no access to the vendor, I would attempt to fix the currency transaction in the source CRM system, and then use the ODBC to post the correct values.

I am assuming that the CRM->ODBC->Evolution is supported in the first place, of course.